# Left join tables, add to on expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have a problem with left join two tables. Please help me.
I have two tables:
So if TableA is

```
A B
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

and TableB is

```
A B
1 d
2 e
```

Then `Select * from TableA left join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A` returns

```
1 a 1 d
2 b 2 e
3 c null null
```

But: `Select * from TableA left join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A where TableB.B = 'e'` returns:

```
2 b 2 e
```

And question, How I can get some like this:

```
2 b 2 e
3 c null null
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: When left join, move the right side table's conditions from WHERE to ON to get true left join behavior. (As it is now, you get regular inner join result...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to get all matches from `TableB`, where `B` field is either equal to `'e'` or `NULL`:

```
Select * 
from TableA 
left join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A 
where (TableB.B = 'e') or (TableB.B is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
Select * from TableA left join TableB on TableA.A = TableB.A 
where TableB.B = 'e' OR TableB.B is NULL
```

And you will get null rows from tableB in addition of rows that match with Table.B='e'